# Detect where characters are in multiple lists

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I want to be able to search a string for characters in different lists.

For example:

list1=['a']

list2=['b']

If a user enters in 'a' for example. Python should print 'list1'

However, if the user input was 'ab', then Python should print list1 and list2

Right now i'm trying to use this function to query the list, but I have to query each list in two separate if statements, like this.

```
def char_search(input_str):
    for char in input_str:
        if char in list1:
            print("lower")
        if char in list2:
            print("Upper")
```

Comment: why did you unmark the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have some lists:

```
list1 = [ ... ]
list2 = [ ... ]
...
```

First you need to be able to collect all that lists together, and then check if each list contains specified item:

```
for lst in list1, list2, list3:
    if mychar in lst:
        print(lst)
        break
else:
    print('Specified lists do not contain', mychar)
```

Note, that it stops as soon as finds item in one of lists. And also, it doesn't print list's name -- if you want it to, you'll need to make list named like:

```
class NamedList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):  # only if you need that specific use
        if self.name is not None: 
            return str(self.name)
        return super().__str__()

# Then use as follows
std = NamedList(['ISO', 'GOST', 'etc'], name='Standards')
sizes = NamedList(['A4', 'Letter'], name='Paper sizes')

smthng = 'Letter'

for nlst in std, sizes:
    if smthng in nlst:
        print(nlst)  # gives you 'Paper sizes'
```

**Correction:** for python 2.x/3.x compatible, use [this](http://pastebin.com/j4wJ7UmC)

Comment: And I don't even mention playing with `vars()` or `globals()` -- it's such a messy non-pythonic way, but yes, you could search the whole namespace for lists, check if specified object is in one of them and print the variable's name associated with that list. It would be bad bad approach, but is exact answer to the exact question asked.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to get your answer to work, but I'm getting a syntax error where you've started defining a function underneath the class NamedList(list)...

Comment: @JoshuaStokes , I think it's because you're using python 2.x. There's no mention of version in original question, so I'm using 3.x in the answer.
If you want to make it work under 2.x, use this one: http://pastebin.com/G7A8a987

Comment: Ah yep, I didn't realise that there was a sperate tag for 'python2.7'. I just assumed that the 'python' tag meant 2.7...

Comment: Ok, the only thing is that this script only works with one character. The idea was to basically iterate through the string and to print the lists where any character in that string appeared. For example if my string was 'abc' and list1 = 'a', list2 = 'b' and list3 = 'c'. I want python to literally print list1 = 'a', list2 = 'b' and list3 = 'c'. However if the string was 'abd', then I only want it to print list1 and list2, because list1 contains 'a, list2 contains 'b', but since list3 contains 'c' and I haven't specfied 'c' in my string, then list3 needs to be ignored...

Comment: In other words, print the lists where each character in the string occurs

Comment: @JoshuaStokes , I'm not sure if it's good to keep only one char in list, because of size overhead. On my machine, `sys.getsizeof([])` gives 64 bytes for list and `sys.getsizeof(NamedList([]))` gives 80 bytes + 49 bytes for str name = 129 bytes overhead.
Maybe `dict(list1='a', list2='b', ...)` would better fit your needs. Also it's more pythonic

Comment: Oh, actually I meant one element, not character, my bad.

Comment: Also I haven't used dict before, I'll try and figure it out, but are you able to post an example using dict with the lists?

Comment: Ok, I just looked at your code, the only problem is that apparently with dicts the items aren't printed in order, also I need to be able to iterate through each character in the input and output any lists where any character in list occurs. For example list 1 = ['a','b',c'], list2 = ['d','e','f'] and then the input was 'abcdef, then python would print list1 = a,b,c, list2 = d,e,f. However if input was acdefg and assuming the lists weren't changed, then the output should be list1 = 'a,c' list2 = 'd,e'.

Comment: @JoshuaStokes then you probably need `OrderedDict` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict
if there are numerous chars in each list, just iterate: `for name, lst in mydict.items():  if char in lst: ...`

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']

input = 'b'

if input in list_1: 
    print "list1"

if input in list_2: 
    print "list2"
```

The output will be 
"list1"

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ['a']
list2 = ['b'] 

if (input[0] in list1 or input[1] in list1)  and (input[0] in list2 or input[1] in list2): 
    print "Choice listed"
```

This works if you want to check that both characters are in at least one list. For more input characters you can add some simple loop logic

Comment: Hi, I had to unmark your answer because I needed to know exactly which list each character was listed in with no limit to how many characters...

Answer (score 1):

```
choice = input("choose a letter")

if choice in list1:
    print(list1)
elif choice in list2:
    print(list2)
else:
    print("choice not listed")
```

Comment: If `choice` is `ab` then this code would print `"choice not listed"`, but the OP specified it should print both lists.